# Snowflake LIKE not populating rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I run the below query:

```
SELECT load_dt, load_fname, exec_date FROM my_table
WHERE TO_DATE(exec_date) = '2021-10-18'
```

I see 3k rows that look like the below:

| load_dt | load_fname | exec_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-19 10:24:25.681 -0400 | FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021-10-12_1247120.csv | 2021-10-18 09:00:00.000 |
| 2021-10-19 10:24:18.543 -0400 | FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021-10-12_3154712.csv | 2021-10-18 09:00:00.000 |

I want to delete the 3k rows so I can reload the correct data based on the load_fname, which is the file location in s3

**please note I'm getting the s3 file location using airflow:**

```
s3_full_path = self.get_partitioned_location(date).replace(
            f's3://{AWS_S3_BUCKET}/', '')
```

which is what I use in my query below after LIKE, it changes depending on date: `FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/`

so I tried this but it came up **empty**:

```
SELECT  load_dt, load_fname FROM my_table
WHERE load_fname like 'FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/'
```

Comment: Not sure if intentional but the string in your LIKE is different to the example load_fname, FK vs FBK. To get more matches you might try using wildcards so LIKE '%FBK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/%'

Comment: @DeanFlinter sorry FBK was a typo in my question but I ran it as the correct value 'FK'. Would adding a '%' to the beginning match everything that begins with FK and adding '%' to the end would it match everything that has 'post_date=2021-10-12/'?  Because I have other rows that look like 'FK/pi/2021-10-22/post_date=2021-10-12/' for example but I don't want to delete those because '2021-10-22' is not data I want deleted

Comment: No it just means that it won't look for a 100% match to the string specified but will also include rows where that string in surrounded by other characters. In your example, since you are not using wildcards, it is effectively equal to so it is the same as WHERE load_fname = 'FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/'. Your example data shows that these rows have more characters after that so your LIKE will not match them unless you also include those. The wildcard will return rows with that string despite the actual data having more characters after it

Comment: Does `WHERE load_fname like 'FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/%'` do what you want ?

Comment: @RobertLong Yes this worked for me, but while testing I noticed adding "%" to the beginning of the string (like Dean Flinter mentioned) also works and seems to give me the same rows as "%" only at the end. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe have read up on LIKE and wildcards, there's a few you can use.
The other option might be to use REGEX expressions, also supported by Snowflake

Comment: The reason why the extra wildcard gives the same results is that your rows start with 'FK'. Robert's suggestion basically says, match all rows that start with 'FK... and end with anything. If your data was like this: 'AFK....' you would get different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description, you want to match rows where the column `load_fname` begins with the following:

```
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/
```

So, that means you want to match all of

```
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021-10-12
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021-10-12_987654321.xyz
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021-10-12_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ.abc
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021-10-12_1247120.csv
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021-10-12_3154712.csv
```

where the last 2 are the ones in your data extract. To acheive this, we simply add the wildcard `%` to the end of the string:

```
WHERE load_fname like 'FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/%'
```

The wildcard literally means - match rows where `%` could be nothing, or any string.

As for the question in the comments:

> I noticed adding "%" to the beginning of the string (like Dean Flinter mentioned) also works and seems to give me the same rows as "%" only at the end. Why is this?

based on the meaning of the wildcard (match rows where `%` could be nothing, or any string) so if the string to match was:

```
%FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/%
```

then this would, in addition to mathing all those I wrote above, ALSO match any string that starts with anything whatsoever of any length (or nothing at all) and is then followed by `FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/` plus anything matched by the trailing `%`. So it would match, for example:

```
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/abcde
abcde/FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/
abcde/FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/abcde
```

There are other wildcards you can use. For example. If you knew that there are exactly 4 characters AFTER the `FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/` then you could use

```
WHERE load_fname LIKE 'FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/____
```

where we have used 4 underscore wild cards, each of which will match 1 and only 1 characters. So this would match:

```
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2022
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2023
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/ABCD
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/abcd
```

but not

```
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/2021-10-12
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/A
FK/pi/2021-10-18/post_date=2021-10-12/
```